# Calculating a confidence interval for percentages for unknown units sas

Tags: r, sas, missing-data, confidence-interval

I need to calculate a confidence interval for rates/percentage, using SAS or R, for a variable that is either 0 or 1 or null and that accounts for unknown values. The rate is (count of 1 / sum(count of 0 plus the count of null)). The total number of units is 7,500. For context, these represent lab values that a person performs, if they have a positive value, then it is a 1. The following example represents the last lab value for each person, but I also have all of the lab values for each person - which may have several 1,0,null's, and unknowns.

Example:

```
Var, Count, Total, Rate, CI (95%) 
1, 2500, 7500, 0.33, [0.30,0.37] 
0, 3400, 7500, 0.45,[0.40,0.50] 
., 1600,7500,0.21,[0.19,0.22]
```

Here is the SAS code for the sample output:

```
Proc Freq data = sample;
     tables var / binomial missing; 
     weight count; 
run;
```

I know that the rate for Var = 1 is not really 33%, it should be around 80%, but the problem is that missing values and values we do not have. Besides null values, there are also missing data that we do not have for all units (this information is all I have, the complete data set is not public).

So I am essentially trying to 'guess' up to the projected 80-85% rate for all the variables with a confidence interval that includes the rate calculated above.

With the data laid out like this, is this possible to project? What would I need, besides the missing values? How can I project that the 33% for Var = 1 is half of what we know? Should i use all of the values for each person and not the last value?

Essentially, I need to construct the following, where the Y axis is the rate/percentage: 
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kristien_Wouters2/publication/283324353/figure/fig1/AS:614178628829196@1523443004471/Mean-viral-load-and-95-confidence-interval-CI-of-Drug-Resource-Enhancement-Against.png

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Recode the missing to 0 seems like the simplest solution. Then take the mean instead. Or if you want a more structured replacement, try using PROC MI to impute the missing values but we'd ned to know a lot more about your data to recommend an approach to handle missing.

Comment: SAS does not differentiate between unknown and null and you didn't explain how that can be differentiated. That's an important part of this question.